# Redux function not available in react-native component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Below I have listed some code I have that should call a function called `fetchOverview()` when the component loads. I am using redux here. However, the problem is that each time I get an error saying:

> TypeError: props.fetchOverview is not a function. (In
> 'props.fetchOverview()', 'props.fetchOverview' is undefined)

I am at a loss as to what I am missing here, since everything seems to map correctly. Here is the key code from the component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {
  fetchOverview,
} from '../state/actions';

export const OverviewScreen = (props) => {
  console.log('props in OverviewScreen: ', props); // fetchOverview not here
  console.log('props.isFetching: ', props.isFetching); // undefined
  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchOverview();
  }, []);
  // More code
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isFetching: state.Overview.isFetching,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchOverview: () => dispatch(fetchOverview()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OverviewScreen);
```

And the `fetchOverview()` function is long, but basically looks like this:

```
export const fetchOverview = () => {
  console.log('fetchOverview() is firing...'); // Never runs
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    // Get local overview from disk
    // Other code
  }
}
```

Comment: Weird!! Are you getting the state props `isFetching` tho? @Muirik

Comment: Also can you share the code snippet for your `fetchOverview` action

Comment: Added a line of code where I call `isFetching()`. When uncommented it returns the same not a function, undefined error.

Comment: But it's called `isFetching` and not `overviewIsFetching` on the `mapStateToProps`

Comment: I think this may be because you're dispatching a function as opposed to an action, could you try `fetchOverview: () => fetchOverview()(dispatch)` on your `mapDispatchToProps()`,

Comment: I don't think so. At one point this worked, but I am making updates to work with the latest react and expo syntax in preparation for EAS. I tried your suggestion and it returned the same error.